# Any easy way to reference all parameters of function call?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I wrote a function "vars_to_string" which is in variadic template way:

```
template< typename ... Args >
std::string strings_to_string(Args const& ... args)
{
    std::ostringstream stream;
    using List = int[];
    (void)List {
        0, ((void)(stream << to_std_string(*args) << " "), 0) ...
    };
    return stream.str();
}

template< typename ... Args >
inline auto vars_to_string(Args const& ... args)
{
    return strings_to_string(&args...).c_str();
}
```

and the function is called like :

```
auto obj_name = vars_to_string("E11", H1, H2, H3, H4, b, D, t, B1, B2, L1, L2);
```

where "H1, H2, H3, H4, b, D, t, B1, B2, L1, L2" are parameters of outer function like :

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT JQ_DLL_API create_E11(double H1, double H2, double H3, double H4, double b, double D, double t, double B1, double B2, double L1, double L2)
{
    jq_assert(H1 > 0);
    jq_assert(H2 > 0);
    jq_assert(H3 > 0);
    jq_assert(H4 > 0);
    jq_assert(b > 0);
    jq_assert(b < B2&& B2 <= B1);
    jq_assert(B2 <= B1);
    jq_assert(L1 > 0);
    jq_assert(L2 > 0);
    jq_assert(L1 >= L2);
    jq_assert(D > 2 * t);

    if (true) {
        auto obj_name = vars_to_string("E11", H1, H2, H3, H4, b, D, t, B1, B2, L1, L2);

        auto pShapePtr = _query_shape_in_memory(obj_name);
...
```

For now, there are other 17 functions like create_E1 ~ create_E17, I have to follow this pattern in each function, which is like :

```
auto obj_name = vars_to_string("E17", H1, H2, H3, H4, HXn, nXn, b1, b2, B1, B2, L1, L2, S1, S2, n1, n2);

auto obj_name = vars_to_string("E16", H1, H2, d, B1, B2, L1, L2, B, H, L, H3);
```

I have to change "H1, H2, d, B1, B2, L1, L2, B, H, L, H3" part for each of the 17 function because the parameters vary for different create_Exx function.

My question : is there any easy way I can do this for these 17 functions ?

Comment: Your code has a dangling pointer. Don't return `.c_str()` called on a temporary object

Comment: It's a bit strange to pass a parameter pack of arguments by pointer. Why aren't you simply using `std::forward`?

Comment: Please explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve. What does "follow this pattern in each function" mean? How do you intend to use `vars_to_string` in combination with `create_E18` and others?

Comment: thanks, will fix the "dangling" pointer problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are no reflections to know parameter names of (current) function.

So you have to call manually your function for each required function by passing parameter manually.

MACRO might "help", if structure of the function are similar enough, with something like

```
DEFINE_FUNCTION(E11, (double, H1) (double, H2)(double, H3)(double, H4)(double, b) /*..*/)
   // ...
}
```

To be replaced by

```
Q_DECL_EXPORT JQ_DLL_API create_E11(double H1, double H2, double H3, double H4, double b, double D, double t, double B1, double B2, double L1, double L2)
{
    auto obj_name = vars_to_string("E11", H1, H2, H3, H4, b, D, t, B1, B2, L1, L2);
    //...
}
```

but not sure the solution is better than the manual way.